# How to get average value in the last 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with calculation of a variable. Lets imagine that we have a table with ID, Date and Salary. And now my task is to find out average salary in the last 6 months for each Date. Is there any other possibility how to get this value instead of Cartesian product?

My proposed resolution:

```
select ID, Date, AVG(Salary2)
from
(
select tab1.ID as ID, tab1.Date as Date, tab2.Date as Date2, tab2.Salary as Salary2
from table tab1
**JOIN**
(select ID, Date, Salary from table) tab2
on tab1.ID = tab2.ID
and tab1.Date >= tab2.Date
and add_months(tab2.Date, 5) >= tab1.Date
) group by ID, Date;
```

I assume that this approach is not effective. I think it is too time-consuming in terms of big tables.

Is there any other approach? Or how should I optimize this script?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide sample data?

Comment: and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so clear what you are asking but I assume you are looking for this:

```
select ID, Date, 
  AVG(Salary2) OVER (
     PARTITION BY ID 
     ORDER BY DATE 
     RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '6' MONTH PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
from table tab1;
```

or as short-cut:

```
select ID, Date, 
  AVG(Salary2) OVER (
     PARTITION BY ID 
     ORDER BY DATE 
     RANGE INTERVAL '6' MONTH PRECEDING)
from table tab1;
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for! Thank you very much!